# Is there a way to add a custom button to an angular TypeAhead directive?

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm currently using an typeahead input directive component which works fine but lacks a certain functionality. The component gets all needed data by a query which is fired as soon as the page is loaded and selects a pre-defined default entry. However there are always at least >15 entries available, but in order to create new record in the same dropdown I want to add a "create button" at the end of the search list. So that if the user types any string and it is unavailable in the dropdown then he/she can create the record through that button. Is there a way to create a customized version of the typescript where I can add a button to save the record entered in the textbox?

```
<h4>Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown</h4>
<pre>Model: {{customPopupSelected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="customPopupSelected" placeholder="Custom popup template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" class="form-control">


<script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
<div class="custom-popup-wrapper"
 ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}"
 style="display: block;"
 ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress"
 aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
<p class="message">select location from drop down.</p>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
  <li class="uib-typeahead-match" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }"
    ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
    <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```